# Installation Play Framework on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ubuntu-14.04

I have a problem with installation of the play framework. I can't configure the play in path on Ubuntu 14.04.

Already run:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/Documentos/play
source ~/.bashrc
sudo chmod a+X /home/me/Documentos/play/play
```

But, when I restart the terminal and type 'play' the terminal shows: 'command not found: play'. What to do?

Answer (score 4):

The `export` only works for current session. When you start a new session, it executes the `~/.bashrc` instructions.

Try following :

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/Documentos/play" >> ~/.bashrc
```

After, that it should work.

Comment: When I'm going to diretory where is the play and run: `sh play` work. But, runing only `play` shows 'command not found: play'

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

- Step 1: login with root access
- Step 2: make "app" folder in /
- Step 3: download play zip file and unzip to /app

Then in a profile or environment script: `export PATH=$PATH:/app/play-x.x.x`

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

the thing here u r doing sets the
path for *only current session*.. u need 2 set the path *permanently*
this is how i did it

**gedit ~/.bashrc**

add the following line on the very bottom

**export ACTIVATOR_HOME=$PATH:/opt/activator-1.3.2**

save it,
it may prompt u for changes in other files as well .. save them also
and restart

here i m using activator.. in ur case u can replace the **/opt/activator-x.x.x** .. with ur relative path 2 the play .. eg: **/dir/play2.2.1** where ever u ve unzipped play